# Custom user meta values in shortcode

Tags: user-meta

I've been searching around but can't find the solution.
I'm trying to show some user meta values for current logged in user in a shortcode.

The meta key is

```
_wc_braintree_credit_card_payment_tokens
```

The example values are

```
a:1:{s:7:"bhaddfh";a:7:{s:7:"default";b:0;s:4:"type";s:11:"credit_card";s:9:"last_four";s:4:"2122";s:9:"card_type";s:10:"mastercard";s:9:"exp_month";s:2:"10";s:8:"exp_year";s:4:"2022";s:18:"billing_address_id";s:2:"sz";}}
```

How do I display "last_four" value, and "card_type" value (which is mastercard in the example here) in a shortcode?

To display them on the frontend for the current user to see.
Maximum one latest card saved in their payment method list (if there are more than one saved).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether users could only reach this page when logged in, so this example includes a check to make sure the current visitor is logged in, otherwise it won't output anything.

```
<?php
// create the shortcode
add_shortcode('wpse_312268_show_cc_info', 'create_wpse_312268_shortcode');
function create_wpse_312268_shortcode() {
    // only do something if user is logged in
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        // get their id
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        // get the specific usermeta value as an array
        $cc_meta = get_user_meta($user_id, '_wc_braintree_credit_card_payment_tokens', false);
        // get specific values from the array
        $last_four = $cc_meta['last_four'];
        $card_type = $cc_meta['card_type'];
        // only show if the values aren't empty
        if(!empty($last_four) && !empty($card_type)) {
            // display with whatever markup you like
            echo "<div class="cc_info">$card_type ending in
                $last_four</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Depending on your needs you may also want to make the text translatable.

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried the code above, changed the echo to      echo '<div class="cc_info">' . $card_type . 'ending in' . $last_four . '</div>';  to make it works. But the card type and last four are not showing up on the frontend, just return empty. Why? I use this plugin for the payment method: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/

Comment: I don't have the same plugins you do so I can't test on my end, but I would suggest simplifying the example code - start with just the `if(is_user_logged_in())` and have it echo something simple. Then if that works, add in the `get_user_meta` and do a `var_dump` of `$cc_meta`, and so on and so forth.